# navbar is moving when a menu item is clicked

Tags: html, css, frontend

```css
:root {
  --primary: #902EC3;
  --secondary: #987EAE;
  --tertiary: #F6EDF7;
  --black: #000;
  --white: #fff;
  --box-shadow: 0 .5rem 1rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

* {
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
}

body {
  background: var(--tertiary);
}

html {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}


/* Header navi start*/

header {
  margin: 0;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background: white;
  box-shadow: var(--box-shadow);
  padding: 28px 0;
}

.logo {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.logo img {
  height: 40px;
  margin-left: 50px;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.navbar {
  display: flex;
  padding: 0%;
  list-style: none;
}

.navbar a {
  color: var(--secondary);
  white-space: nowrap;
  margin: 30px;
  margin-left: 60px;
}

.navbar a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: var(--primary);
}

.main {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin-left: 70px;
}

.main a {
  white-space: nowrap;
  margin-right: 25px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  color: var(--secondary);
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.user {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.user i {
  color: var(--primary);
}

.main a:hover {
  color: var(--primary);
  text-decoration: none;
}

#menu-icon {
  font-size: 35px;
  color: var(--secondary);
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 10001;
  display: none;
}

@media (max-width: 1280px) {
  header {
    padding: 0.9rem 2%;
    transition: .2s;
  }
  .navbar a {
    padding: 5px 0;
    margin: 0px 20px;
  }
  .logo img {
    height: 30px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 1090px) {
  #menu-icon {
    display: block;
  }
  .navbar {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    right: -100%;
    width: 250px;
    height: 29vh;
    background: var(--primary);
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    border-radius: 10px;
  }
  .navbar a {
    display: block;
    margin: 5px 28px;
    color: white;
    padding: 4px 50px;
  }
  .navbar a:hover {
    color: var(--secondary);
    transform: translateY(5px);
  }
  .navbar.open {
    right: 2%;
  }
  .logo img {
    height: 20px;
  }
}


/* Header navi end*/


/*-Slide Animation Start-*/

.slideshow-container {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}

.prev,
.next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  margin-top: -22px;
  padding: 16px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
}

.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

.prev:hover,
.next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

.text {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

.dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active,
.dot:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}

.fade {
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {
    opacity: .4
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1
  }
}


/*-Slide Animation Ends-*/


/* Text in Home Start */

.parentcont {
  margin-top: 50px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.bodytext {
  width: 1000px;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Cormorant Garamond', serif;
}

.bodytext h1 {
  font-family: 'Times New Roman';
  font-size: 50px;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.bodytext h2 {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: 'Raleway';
  margin: 30px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}


/* Text in Home End */


/* service start */

.services-container {
  margin-top: 5%;
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, blueviolet, #F6EDF7);
  padding: 20px 9% 100px;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.services-container .heading {
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  font-size: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.services-container .box-container {
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(270px, 1fr));
  gap: 15px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.services-container .box-container .box {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 30px 20px;
}

.services-container .box-container .box img {
  height: 450px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.services-container .box-container .box h3 {
  color: #444;
  font-size: 22px;
  padding: 10px 0;
}

.services-container .box-container .box p {
  color: #777;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 1.8;
}

.services-container .box-container .box .services-btn {
  margin-top: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: #333;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 17px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 8px 25px;
}

.services-container .box-container .box .services-btn:hover {
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.services-container .box-container .box:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 10px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  text-decoration: none;
  transform: scale(1.03);
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .services-container {
    height: 100%;
    padding: 40px;
    margin-top: 7%;
  }
  .services-container .heading {
    font-size: 40px;
  }
  .services-container .box-container .box {
    padding: 20px;
  }
  .services-container .box-container .box h3 {
    font-size: 18px;
  }
  .services-container .box-container .box p {
    font-size: 14px;
  }
  .services-container .box-container .box .services-btn {
    font-size: 14px;
  }
}


/* service end */


/* Appointment panel start*/

.container {
  margin-top: 150px;
  width: 20%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #FFF;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.form-data {
  background-color: #FFF;
}

.form-body {
  padding: 20px;
}

.form-head {
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #CCC;
}

.form-head h2 {
  font-size: 26px;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.form-row {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.form-control {
  background-color: var(--tertiary);
  border-radius: 0px;
  font-size: 15px;
  height: 40px;
}

.form-control:focus {
  box-shadow: none;
  border: 2px solid var(--primary);
}

.btn-appointment {
  border: 3px solid var(--primary);
  background-color: var(--primary);
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  transition: color 0.4s linear;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.btn-appointment:hover {
  background-color: var(--secondary);
  border: 3px solid var(--secondary);
}

.datepicker td,
.datepicker th {
  padding: 5px;
}

.dropdown-menu.datepicker {
  max-width: 300px !important;
}


/* Appointment panel end*/


/* Products panel start*/

.product-container {
  margin-top: 5%;
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, blueviolet, #F6EDF7);
  padding: 20px 9% 100px;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.product-container .heading {
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  font-size: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.product-container .box-container {
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(270px, 1fr));
  gap: 15px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.product-container .box-container .box {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 30px 20px;
}

.product-container .box-container .box img {
  height: 450px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.product-container .box-container .box h3 {
  color: #444;
  font-size: 22px;
  padding: 10px 0;
}

.product-container .box-container .box p {
  color: #777;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 1.8;
}

.product-container .box-container .box .product-btn {
  margin-top: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: #333;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 17px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 8px 25px;
}

.product-container .box-container .box .product-btn:hover {
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.product-container .box-container .box:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 10px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  text-decoration: none;
  transform: scale(1.03);
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .product-container {
    height: 100%;
    padding: 40px;
    margin-top: 7%;
  }
  .product-container .heading {
    font-size: 40px;
  }
  .product-container .box-container .box {
    padding: 20px;
  }
  .product-container .box-container .box h3 {
    font-size: 18px;
  }
  .product-container .box-container .box p {
    font-size: 14px;
  }
  .product-container .box-container .box .product-btn {
    font-size: 14px;
  }
}


/* Products panel end*/


/* address start */

.address {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 700px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: var(--primary);
  margin-top: 50px;
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.map {
  margin-top: 20px;
  width: 100%;
}

.address-text {
  font-size: 20px;
}


/* address start */


/* Footer start*/

footer {
  margin-top: 40px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: var(--primary);
  height: auto;
  width: 100vw;
  font-family: "Open Sans";
  padding-top: 10px;
  color: #fff;
}

.footer-content {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
}

.footer-content h3 {
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  font-weight: 200;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  line-height: 3rem;
}

.footer-content p {
  max-width: 200px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  line-height: 28px;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.socials {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 1rem 0 3rem 0;
}

.socials li {
  margin: 0 10px;
}

.socials a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
}

.socials a i {
  font-size: 2rem;
  transition: color .4s ease;
}

.socials a:hover i {
  color: var(--tertiary);
}

.footer-bottom {
  background: var(--secondary);
  width: 100vw;
  padding: 20px 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.footer-bottom p {
  font-size: 14px;
  word-spacing: 2px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}

.footer-bottom span {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  opacity: .4;
  font-weight: 200;
}


/* Footer ends*/
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewpoort" content="width=device-width, intitial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/datepicker.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/remixicon@3.4.0/fonts/remixicon.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/boxicons@latest/css/boxicons.min.css">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Cardo&family=Poppins:wght@500;600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>

  <!-- Header start -->

  <header class="header">

    <div class="logo">

      <a href="#"> <img src="assets/images/websitelogo.png"></a>


    </div>

    <ul class="navbar text-md mt-1">
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="btnbook">Book Now</a></li>

    </ul>

    <div class="main">
      <a href="#" class="user"><i class="ri-user-fill"></i>Sign In</a>
      <a href="#">Register</a>
      <div class="bx bx-menu" id="menu-icon"></div>
    </div>



  </header>

  <!-- Header end -->

  <!-- Sliding start -->



  <div class="slideshow-container">


    <div class="mySlides">

      <img src="assets/images/slide1.jpg" style="width:100%">

    </div>

    <div class="mySlides">

      <img src="assets/images/slide2.jpg" style="width:100%">

    </div>

    <div class="mySlides">

      <img src="assets/images/slide3.jpg" style="width:100%">

    </div>


    <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
    <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
  </div>
  <br>

  <div style="text-align:center">
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
  </div>

  <!-- Sliding end -->

  <!-- Text start -->

 
  <div class="parentcont">

    <div class="bodytext">
      <h1>
        Treatments to achieve your dream skin
      </h1>
      <h2>
        Taking care of your skin is the key to that glow. No matter how much makeup you slather on,
        on a daily basis, the radiance you get from healthy skin hits very differently.
        These skincare motivational quotes will remind you why healthy skin is in.
        <br>
        <br>
        We strive to offer quality services and products at reasonable price and to provide clients with satisfying,
        balanced and therapeutic facial and body treatments; which will provide more financial returns to its major
        stakeholders.

      </h2>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Text end -->

  <!-- Map start -->

  <div class="address">
    <div class="address-text">

      <p><strong>If you have any inquiries you can visit our head office located at: </strong> </p>
    </div>
    <div class="map">
      <iframe
        src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d3866.3748251795437!2d121.09447487595926!3d14.289641184612519!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x3397d85e00a81891%3A0x6dd96a0cbef61bbc!2sZoto%20Building!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sph!4v1684915760800!5m2!1sen!2sph"
        width="600" height="450" style="border:0;" allowfullscreen="" aria-hidden="false" tabindex="0"></iframe>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Map end -->


  <!-- footer start -->

  <footer>
    <div class="footer-content">
      <h3>Lynderm Facial Center</h3>

      <ul class="socials">
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="footer-bottom">
      <p>Copyright &copy;2023 Lynderm Facial Center</span></p>
    </div>
  </footer>
  </div>
</body>

<!-- Optional JavaScript -->
<!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
<script src="assets/js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/sliding.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/nav.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

The navbar moves if I clicked menu items, the size increase like small amount then goes back to normal in a second

I tried setting the margin to auto but it still happens, why is this happening

I hope someone can help me fix this problem and help me become more knowledgeable in css and html

here's the css code

```
:root {
  --primary: #902EC3;
  --secondary: #987EAE;
  --tertiary: #F6EDF7;
  --black: #000;
  --white: #fff;
  --box-shadow: 0 .5rem 1rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);

}

* {
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
  border: none;

}

body {
  background: var(--tertiary);
  
}

html {

  overflow-x: hidden;
}


/* Header navi start*/

header {

  margin: auto;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background: white;
  box-shadow: var(--box-shadow);
  padding: 28px 0;


}

.logo {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.logo img {
  height: 40px;
  margin-left: 50px;
  max-width: 100%;

}

.navbar {
  display: flex;
  padding: 0%;
  list-style: none;

}

.navbar a {
  color: var(--secondary);
  white-space: nowrap;
  margin: 30px;
  margin-left: 60px;
  transition: all .50s ease;
}

.navbar a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: var(--primary);
}

.navbar a.active {
  color: var(--primary);
}

.main {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin-left: 70px;
}

.main a {
  white-space: nowrap;
  margin-right: 25px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  color: var(--secondary);
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  font-weight: 500;
  transition: all .50s ease;
}

.user {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.user i {
  color: var(--primary);
}

.main a:hover {
  color: var(--primary);
  text-decoration: none;
}

#menu-icon {
  font-size: 35px;
  color: var(--secondary);
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 10001;
  display: none;
}

@media (max-width: 1280px) {
  header {
    padding: 0.9rem 2%;
    transition: .2s;
  }

  .navbar a {
    padding: 5px 0;
    margin: 0px 20px;
  }

  .logo img {
    height: 30px;
  }

}


@media (max-width: 1090px) {
  #menu-icon {
    display: block;
  }

  .navbar {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    right: -100%;
    width: 250px;
    height: 29vh;
    background: var(--primary);
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    border-radius: 10px;
    transition: all .50s ease;
  }

  .navbar a {
    display: block;
    margin: 5px 28px;
    color: white;
    padding: 4px 50px;
    transition: all .50s ease;
  }

  .navbar a:hover {
    color: var(--secondary);
    transform: translateY(5px);

  }

  .navbar a.active {
    color: var(--secondary);
  }

  .navbar.open {
    right: 2%;
   
  }

  .logo img {
    height: 20px;
  }

}
```

Comment: Can't be sure without a working demo, but maybe comment out `transform: translateY(5px);` and see if that helps.

Comment: it still happens @ralph.m

Comment: I see you figured out how to post the code demo. I don't see any issue with the links. :-/

Comment: Okay. Well the point is to post the code that shows the issue. Anyhow, you have other rules in your CSS that will distort some links on hover, such as `transform: scale(1.03);`, `transform: translateY(5px);`

Comment: I only input the navigation code but when I run the whole code in vscode the problem is still there @ralph.m

Comment: do you think the problem occurs not in the navigation but the rest of the code?

Comment: yes, but that code doesn't concern the navigation because it is only on hover, the problem is when I click the menu links @ralph.m

Comment: Not reproducible. Include just enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem. For help with this, read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).